# PHP/AJAX - Like button, need some help on the PHP part

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm trying to create this like button which goes +1 after clicking on it. You can only click the like once (like is bonded to the account with what u logged in, so a user can not 15x like the same post.)

In my **HTML** I have this button

```
<a class="like" id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" href="index.php?id=.$rows['ID']">like</a>
```

As my **AJAX/JQuery** I have these

```
$('a.like').on('click',function () {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');


    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/post_like.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: ({ id: id }), // first id is the name, second is the actual id variable we just created
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            // you can do stuff in here before you send the data, display spinner gif etc
            alert('sending the like');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // same here but when the ajax request is successful
            // the data variable is coming from the echo of your PHP script
            alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            // yet again but on completion
            alert('completed the like');
        }

    });

    // stops the browser following the link (href) in the a tag
    return false;

});
```

Now here is the part where I am struggling, mainly the PHP handling. We have created a load more button which loads more posts which works well. The code is as follows. How can I know work out the like part in the same way as the load more button?

```
<?php
include_once("../classes/db.class.php");
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$output = "";
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
if(isset($limit)){
    if($limit != ""){
        $conn = db::getInstance();
        $query ="SELECT posts.id, posts.post_title, posts.picture ,posts.description, posts.location, posts.post_date
                  FROM posts
                  INNER JOIN friends 
                  ON posts.user_id = friends.user1_id OR posts.user_id = friends.user2_id
                  WHERE friends.user1_id='$userid' OR friends.user2_id='$userid'
                  ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
                  LIMIT $limit";
        $result = $conn->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();

        while($row = $result->fetch()) {

            $output.=' <div class="post">';
            $output .='<div class="post_desc"><p>'. $row['post_title'].'</p></div>';
            $output .='<div class="post__picture"><img src="'. $row['picture'].'" alt=""></div>';
            $output .='<div class="post_desc"><p>'. $row['description'].'</p></div>';
            $output .=' <div class="post_date">'. $row['post_date'].'</div>';
            $output .='</div>';


        };
        echo $output;
    }
}
else{

}

?>
```

Our database is as follows.
[image]

Comment: What is the specific question/problem here? You need to narrow this down more

Comment: 1. What do you `like`, can you like more than one thing? 2. Where is the PHP that stores and retrieves the likes for the userid?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can set the `id` column freely, and the `userid` and `postid` sections are alphanumerical, you can require the `id` column to be unique. The following will then always work:

```
include_once("../classes/db.class.php");
$conn = db::getInstance();

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$postid = $_POST['id'];
$id = "$userid/$postid";

$query = "INSERT INTO likes (id, user_id, post_id) VALUES ('$id', '$userid', '$postid')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo json_encode({postid: postid});
} else {
    // There was a small problem processing the like
    // You might want to add a check in your success function just to be sure
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}
```

However, be sure to add a few tests to prevent SQL injections (e.g. by ensuring `$postid` consists only of integers). If no such guarantee can be made, you should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php#60496) thread.
Otherwise (e.g. if `id` is generated using `AUTO_INCREMENT`), you'd have to add a test which tries to retrieve (`$userid`, `$postid`) to check if it doesn't exist already:

```
if (conn->query("SELECT 1 FROM likes WHERE userid=$userid AND postid=$postid")->num_rows == 0) {
    // Place the code starting from `$id = ` in here.
};
```